# what is the command of select in grid view asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `GridView` called `gridview1`

What I want is that if the user select or click on specific row some action will happen.

For example I want to get the value from that row and store it in a new variable.

How can I do it? I'm confused about what I should do to get the value?

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    string stuId  = ?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged = "OnSelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Country" ItemStyle-Width="150">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Country") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:ButtonField Text="Select" CommandName="Select" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<br />
<u>Selected Row Values: </u>
    <br />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="lblValues" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

**aspx.cs  code**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Id"), new DataColumn("Name"), new DataColumn("Country") });
        dt.Rows.Add(1, "John Hammond", "United States");
        dt.Rows.Add(2, "Mudassar Khan", "India");
        dt.Rows.Add(3, "Suzanne Mathews", "France");
        dt.Rows.Add(4, "Robert Schidner", "Russia");
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Accessing BoundField Column
    string name = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;

    //Accessing TemplateField Column controls
    string country = (GridView1.SelectedRow.FindControl("lblCountry") as Label).Text;

    lblValues.Text = "<b>Name:</b> " + name + " <b>Country:</b> " + country;
}
```

you simply copy and paste your issue is resolve.

Comment: I am using TemplateField . and  this works for me . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you could use like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "false" 
    OnRowCommand = "OnRowCommand">
 <Columns>    
 <asp:ButtonField CommandName = "ButtonField"  DataTextField = "StudID"
            ButtonType = "Button"/>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>


protected void OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    GridViewRow gvRow = GridView1.Rows[index]; 
}
```

Comment: What is the value of gvRow after execute these last two lines ? is it whole row ?

Comment: @AL3MS yes it will be whole row. you need to find your controls like Label, Textboxes from it